# Make a View for forecasting based on structure of a View with existing data in SQL

Tags: sql, self-join, forecasting

In my database I have a **View** `Revenues` with fields `ProductID`, `EditionID`, `Year`, `January`, `February`, `March`,..., `December`.

I need to display in Excel for each `ProductID` and `EditionID` all the year and months revenues in a single record. In order to do that I execute the query:

```
SELECT *
FROM Revenus r1
JOIN Revenues r2
ON r1.ProductID = r2.ProductID
AND r1.EditionID = r2.EditionID
WHERE r1.[Year] <> r2.[Year]
```

That works perfectly if there at the most two different years per `ProductID` and `EditionID`. However since the sheet will be used also for forecasting purposes, I have been asked to have the `Year` and months with a 10 years horizon. That means besides the data already existing in the database, given starting year 2013, I must have years and related month till 2023. The months related data must be equal to zero if there is no `Year` yet in the database.

I tried with pivot table but it does not sound as the right solution. I might try with a foreach but I read on the web that is a bad practice. The best solution, yet a bit dirty, might be to join the existing data with a View built on the fly with empty records for months and increase the year for each "iteration". Anybody might help? Thanks

**UPDATE**

[image: Query example]

Same of 2015 till 2023

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: When you say all the year and months in a single record, you mean 120+ fields wide in one record?

Comment: Sorry maybe it is a bit confusing, see update